# How to Change the Website icon for a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to change the logo of the website which is made on flutter
I am using this library [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons).
But this only works for android and ios, Is there any way to change the web app also?

Comment: I believe the icon of a flutter website is read from here `projectPath/web/favicon.png` so just replace this file with whatever icon you want to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `web` folder in your project, then you can see a file called `favicon.png`. Replace the file with any png file which is not bigger than 16 pixels.

The picture should be

- PNG or ICO formatted
- Small-sized (for faster load)

After this, you need to rebuild the project!

I think this is the best way to implement the answer to this question.